# How to implement single pass clustering algorithm in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-mining

How to implement single pass clustering algorithm in python

I have the algorithm, but I am pretty new with the programing stuff, could anybody help me to code this

Check the attached image for algorithm

[image: single pass clustering algorithm]

Comment: Hi @corey, Welcome to SO. Please read the [ask] page. Do note, SO is not a place to ask for questions like "please help me code this". Please attempt the problem yourself and incase you face any specific issue, please feel free to elaborate it on SO.

Comment: Just to add, what you have posted is the Kmeans algorithm. It is NOT a single pass algorithm. In fact, there is no clustering algorithm that is `single pass` in its loosest definition. Please use sklearn to implement kmeans if you are new to `programming stuff` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: @AkshaySehgal thanks for the reply but my prof said this is algorithm of single pass and not kmeans anyway doing k means will take same steps as far as above image algorithm ?

Comment: The algorithm you have posted has a for loop if you notice. How can it be single pass? Clustering is an iterative process. Very hard for it to be single pass.